# jQuery UI Draggable Helper Issue?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a bunch of photos on the left and I want to drag them into a slot on the right, but when I drag the images to the slot on the right, the one on the left disappears.

I added the `helper: 'clone'` to my draggable function and it is still removing it. I am using ui.draggable.css positioning to position the dragged element ontop of the slot. I think that may be the issue, but I am unsure as to how to fix it?

Is there a way to clone the object before dragging it and then have the dragged item snap into the droppable spot? Without having to use `.css` to manually move the draggable item overtop of the slot.

Comment: Did you try the `snap` and `snapMode` [options](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#options) instead of positioning the dragged element yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish what you're asking is to combine it with the droppable class.   Here's a very basic idea of what I'm referring to:

```
<img class="draggable" src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/keys.png">
<img class="draggable" src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png">
<img class="draggable" src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/info-close.png">

<div id="dropzone" class="dropzone" style=""></div>


$(function() {
    $(".draggable").draggable({
        helper: "clone",
        grid: [ 20,20 ]
    });
    $("#dropzone").droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            $this.append(ui.draggable);
        }
    });
});
```

I added a jsfiddle(http://jsfiddle.net/fordlover49/deb9W/) for you as well.